# Convert all words to upper

Tags: r

I need to convert all words in a vector to upper format.
Assume that I have this vector :

```
V <- c("Xyz", "zEr", "Zyx")
```

The result should be:

```
"XYZ" "ZER" "ZYX"
```

How can I do it please?

Comment: Have you tried `toupper(V)`?

Comment: @Codeer, oh thank you it works

Comment: @Shique, No it is not duplicated

Comment: Glad it worked! I feel like there should be a duplicate of this but I am not able to find it so far. (The linked one seems too complex for this question).